# Azure pipeline environment variables failing

Tags: python, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

I have the following yaml pipeline build file:

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

jobs:
- job: 'Test'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      Python36:
        python.version: '3.6'
    maxParallel: 4

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
      architecture: 'x64'
    env:
      POSTGRES: $(POSTGRES)

  - script: python -m pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'

  - script: |
      pip install pytest
      pytest tests -s --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml
    displayName: 'pytest'
```

I set the variable `POSTGRES` in the pipeline settings as a secret variable. In the python code all environment variables are read with the call

```
if not os.getenv(var):
    raise ValueError(f'Environment variable \'{var}\' is not set')
```

When the build is executed it will throw exactly the above error for the `POSTGRES` variable. Are the environment variables not set correctly?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you need to set it on the step where you use it, it doesnt persist across steps?

Comment: So if I have 10 steps and access the envs in each of them, then I'd have to repeatedly set them 10 times? That seems highly unlikely...

Comment: it would probably take you 1 minute to try out my hypothesis... sure you can just not do anything and that will probably get you really far ;)

Comment: But the env as I set them are on a step basis, I use them then in the `- script` part of the same step. Or did you mean to set them on each `- script`

Comment: not on each, you only need to set them on the pytest step in this particular example, set them only where you need them

Comment: I have tried it on a per step basis but still doesn't wokr

Comment: Have you tried setting environment variables for another type of script (e.g. powershell or bash), and checking whether they're available that way? It could help you ascertain whether you have a pipeline problem or a python problem.

Comment: I have tried `echo $(POSTGRES)` in one of the steps and the output is empty

Comment: @wasp256 were you able to find a solution? I'm stuck in the same issue.

Comment: When defining the variables there's an option to encrypt them which i had selected; when removing that encryption I was able to set them correctly in the pipeline

Answer (score 3):

To make the environment variable available in the Python script, you need to define it in the step where it's used:

```
  - script: |
      pip install pytest
      pytest tests -s --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml
    displayName: 'pytest'
    env:
      POSTGRES: $(POSTGRES)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this but...
If you take a look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) it says:

> Unlike a normal variable, they are not automatically decrypted into
>   environment variables for scripts. You can explicitly map them in,
>   though.

So it looks like you were doing it right. Maybe try using a different name for the mapped variable. It could be the name of the initial encrypted variable is confounding the mapping (because it's already a variable it won't remap it).