# Getting Django env vars into Azure Pipelines for running unit tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I've tried a few ways of doing this and every time the step fails saying:

```
  ...
  File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/api/config/settings.py", line 23, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.10/x64/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DJANGO_SECRET_KEY'
```

This is template in question that fails at the last `script` step:

```
parameters:
- name: serviceName
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: pathName
  type: string
  default: ''

jobs:
- job: 
  displayName: Running unit tests for ${{ parameters.serviceName }}...
  variables:
    servicesChanged: $[ stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChanges.servicesChanged'] ]
  condition: or(contains(variables['servicesChanged'], '${{ parameters.serviceName }}'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8'
  - script: |
      cd ${{ parameters.pathName }} && 
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip && 
      pip install -r requirements.txt
    displayName: Install requirements for ${{ parameters.pathName }}...
  - script: cd ${{ parameters.pathName }} &&  coverage run --omit='manage.py,config/*,.venv*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' manage.py test
    displayName: Run unit tests and coverage for ${{ parameters.pathName }}...
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFiles: reports/django-basic.xml
      testRunTitle: ${{ parameters.pathName }} Tests
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Throughout my Django app, I read in env vars with `os.environ[ENV_VAR]` which has worked fine so far.

This is what I've tried:

### Setting Vars in the Pipeline

What I thought would be the easiest, but the least desirable way of doing this. I say that because I have all these values in Azure Key Vault, so it would be duplicative updating these in two places.

[image]

Still, I get the error that `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` is `None`.

### Azure Key Vault Task

Pretty much follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) which involves setting up a Service Principle between AKV and ADO.

I then made a `secrets.yaml` with this:

```
steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    KeyVaultName: $(keyVaultName)
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: false
```

This task runs fine and you can see it ADO Pipelines pulling all of the values from AKV.

And updated the Python unit test template to:

```
parameters:
- name: serviceName
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: pathName
  type: string
  default: ''

jobs:
- job: 
  displayName: Running unit tests for ${{ parameters.serviceName }}...
  variables:
    servicesChanged: $[ stageDependencies.Changed.Changes.outputs['detectChanges.servicesChanged'] ]
  condition: or(contains(variables['servicesChanged'], '${{ parameters.serviceName }}'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
  steps:
  - template: secrets.yaml
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8'
    env:
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: $(PROD-DJANGOSECRETKEY)
  - script: |
      cd ${{ parameters.pathName }} && 
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip && 
      pip install -r requirements.txt
    displayName: Install requirements for ${{ parameters.pathName }}...
  - script: cd ${{ parameters.pathName }} &&  coverage run --omit='manage.py,config/*,.venv*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' manage.py test
    displayName: Run unit tests and coverage for ${{ parameters.pathName }}...
```

I was led to believe that I could just map `env:` to the `UsePythonVersion@0` task by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55623419/azure-pipeline-environment-variables-failing). That is apparently not the case because even hard coding a string there does nothing.

### Question

What am I doing wrong here and what is the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are close actually. So you have this:

```
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.8'
    env:
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: $(PROD-DJANGOSECRETKEY)
```

But this sets only DJANGO_SECRET_KEY for this task. So if you need it in another task you also need to set the same env mapping there.